# Host Interceptor gives localhost as hostname in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to write my apache logs from my ec2 instances. I want the logs separated by hostname.

I'm using host interceptor to get the hostname. My configuration is below.

`agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors = i1 hostname
agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.i1.type = timestamp
agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.hostname.type = host
agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.hostname.useIP = false 
agent1.sources.spooldir-source1.interceptors.hostname.preserveExisting = true`

But, flume writes the logs to directory called `localhost`. This is not suitable for me.

I have not changed the default hostname of aws instance.

ie,
If the default hostname is like the below one.

> bitnami@ip-10-242-197-46:~$ hostname
>
> ip-10-242-197-46

I want the logs to be written in a directory called `ip-10-242-197-46` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I have asked same question in severfault. I think this question belongs to severfault.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Changing the order of entries in `/etc/hosts` did the trick. I moved the entry for `ip-10-242-197-46` to the top of host file. Hope this helps someone.